# Where to store configuration information in large Distributed Enterprise System

Tags: enterprise, configuration-management

This is more of a high level question. But say you have a large number of applications, many of them distributed (server/clusters) and they share configuration parameter.

What is a good way to store this application specific configuration (preferable in a central place) without relying on a single point of failure.

For configuration I mean things like "database server addresses", "web services endpoint", "Logging file name" and even why not some business related constants and parameter.
Some of this parameter could eventually be changed at runtime so the application needs to be able to also query dynamically these parameters.

I can think of an application storing the configuration at a local file (forget about the format) or a central database to store the same.

But I would like to ask the community if there are standards for handling configuration of multiple distributed systems.

Thanks.

Comment: This question would be a better fit on [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache [ZooKeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/) is a centralized service for maintaining configuration information, naming, providing distributed synchronization, and providing group services.